# PowerShell session/environment isolation - Jobs sharing same context?

Tags: powershell, azure-automation

I'm testing a workflow runbook that utilizes Add-Type to add some custom C# code.

All of a sudden I started getting 'type already exists' errors on subsequent test jobs, as if a new PSSession is not being created.

In other words, it looks like new jobs are sharing the same execution context. I only get this locally if I try to run the same command twice per PS instance.

The type in question is a static class with some Extension methods. Since it also happens to be the first type declared in the source block, I don't doubt other non-static types would throw errors as well.

I've executed this handfuls of times already, so I fully expect that 'eventually' this will stop happening, but I can't seem to force it, and I have no idea what I could've done to trip it into this situation, either.

Seeing evidence of shared execution contexts across jobs like this - even (especially?) if only temporal - makes me wonder if some or all of the general execution inconsistencies we've seen in the past when making & deploying changes & performing subsequent tests soon-after are related to this.

I'm tempted to think that this is simply a part of the difference between a Test Job and a 'real' one, but that raises questions about the validity of the Test jobs themselves WRT mimicking Published Jobs.

Are all Azure Automation Jobs supposed to execute in Isolation? Can this be controlled/exploited by a developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each automation account has its own isolated sandboxes where its jobs run. Those sandboxes are distributed among a number of worker machines. For test jobs, to try to improve job start time since [make code change, retest] over and over is very common, Automation reuses the same sandbox as used for previous test jobs of this runbook, if the sandbox has not been cleaned up yet, so that sandboxes do not have to be spun up for each unique test job (sandbox creation is one reason for a longer job start time than desired). Due to this behavior, if you execute test jobs of the same runbook within a short amount of time, you will get the behavior you're seeing above.

However, even for production jobs, jobs of the same automation account (across runbooks) can share the same sandboxes. We randomly distribute jobs across our worker machines, so its possible job A is queued for execution and is placed on worker W, then 5 minutes later, job B is queued for execution and is placed on worker W as well. If job A and job B are of the same automation account and have the same "demands" in terms of modules / module versions, they will be placed in the same sandbox, if job A's sandbox is still around. "Module / module version demands" does not mean the modules used by the runbook, but the modules / latest module versions that existed in the automation account at the time when the job was started / runbook was scheduled (for jobs started via schedule) / runbook was assigned to a webhook (for jobs started via webhook)

In terms of resolving your specific problem, you could surround Add-Type with a try, catch statement, or maybe use `Add-Type -IgnoreWarnings`

Comment: Thanks Joe - that's a really helpful explanation of the execution process. Is this documented anywhere else in more detail? Ideally, this would be deployed as a module (not inline c#), and in that case the `get-module` flow works well for defending against it if needed. The potential for sanbox reuse is good to know, to code proactively for consistent execution.